# How to show key value options in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angular

My object is returned in this format:

```
{
  "1":
    {"130":"Option1"},
  "2":
    {"133":"Option4"},
  "3":
    {"131":"Option3"},
  "6":
    {"132":"Option5"}
}
```

I want to show values for eg. `{"132":"Option5"}` in select drop down as **132** is value and **Option5** as text in angular 2

I tried:

```
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in modeltest.fieldOptions"
  value="{{key}}">
  [[value]]
</option>`
```

Currently it is printing shown in images.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new function in your controller as `keyValue()` that will take the object and return the value as `Object.keys()` do not work directly in an Angularjs expression:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.modeltest = {
    "fieldOptions" : {
    "1":
    {"130":"Option1"},
    "2":
        {"133":"Option4"},
    "3":
        {"131":"Option3"},
    "6":
        {"132":"Option5"}
      }
   };
   $scope.keyValue = function(obj){
     return obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in modeltest.fieldOptions"
            value="{{keyValue(value)}}">
       {{keyValue(value)}}
</option>
```